# Get href from element in a table using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to access the href attribute within an element of a table using puppeteer. The table is fairly standard and set up like so:

```
<table id="sessions">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>abcd</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>
          <a href="www.example.com"> Example </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I search the table for the row that has the `innerText == "abcd"` in column n and then take the link in column m of the same row. I will then use the link in page.goto()
I would be very grateful for any help!

**Edit:**
I have tried the following so far, but it's a little over-complicated and doesn't work

```
const text = await page.$$eval('#sessions tr', rows => {
    return Array.from(rows, row => {
      const columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
      return cols = Array.from(columns, column => column.innerText)
    });
  });

  const links = await page.$$eval('#sessions tr', rows => {
    return Array.from(rows, row => {
      const columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
      return cols = Array.from(columns, column => column.innerHTML)
    });
  });

for (var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++){
      if (result[i][2] == "abcd"){
        usefulLink = links[i][5];
        break;
      }
  }
```

**Edit 2:** A huge thanks to vsemozhebuty for helping, this is where I am at so far:

```
  const href = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const table = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#sessions tr'));
    const tr = [...table.row].find(({ cells }) => cells[0].innerText === "abcd");
    if (tr) return tr.cells[1].querySelector('a').href;
    return null;
  });
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? could you update the question with your work please?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
      <table id="sessions">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>abcd</td>
              <td><a href="https://www.example.com">Example</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>efgh</td>
              <td><a href="https://www.example.org">Example</a></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>`;

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  const href = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const table = document.querySelector('table');
    const tr = [...table.rows].find(({ cells }) => cells[0].innerText === "abcd");
    if (tr) return tr.cells[1].querySelector('a').href;
    return null;
  });
  console.log(href); // https://www.example.com/
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I really appreciate the help. I got an error, `table.row is not iterable`. I added `Array.from(document....)` and have been able to show that the table is found by using `return table.map(cell => cell.innerText);` But can't seem to crack the `const tr =` ... line of code. See Edit 2 for details.

Comment: You've overcomplicated a bit. Try just: `const trs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#sessions tr'));
const tr = trs.find(({ cells }) => cells[0].innerText === "abcd");`